# default rails nested controller rspec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controllers, stub

So, I have a controller nested within 2 others

here's an example route 
products/123/conditions/321/inventories/121

and the controllers are nested like this as well, so I'm trying to figure out what to stub out in my tests.

Product.should_receive(:find) does not get called.  I'm wondering what will be the first thing called so I can begin to stub it.

I could find this out if I had a way to take a class and listen to all methods called on it.  Is there a way to do that?  I tried redefining Products to nil, so that any method called would throw an error, it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I could find this out if I had a way to take a class and listen to all methods called on it. Is there a way to do that?*

Well, you could replace the class with a mock:

`Product = mock`

From that point on, any method called on `Product` should generate a failure, e.g. "Mock received unexpected message :find".